# CasperJS - using fill() vs evaluate() vs sendKeys()

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm learning CasperJS and have been able to login to a website using `fill()` but haven't been able to using `this.evaluate()` or `this.sendKeys()`

What am I doing wrong with `this.evaluate()` & `this.sendKeys()`?

This works:

```
casper.then(function() {    
    this.fill('form[class="login-form"]', {
      'session_key': 'username',
      'session_password': 'password'
    }, true);
});
```

However, neither of these do:

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function(username, password) {
        document.querySelector('input#login-email').value = username;
        document.querySelector('input#login-password').value = password;
        document.querySelector('input[value="Sign in"]').click();
    }, 'username', 'password');
})
```

or

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.sendKeys('input#login-email', 'username');
    this.sendKeys('input#login-password', 'password');
    this.click('input[value="Sign in"]')
})
```

Comment: I don't see the page markup, so it might be possible that those selectors are plain wrong. Another possibility is that clicking doesn't work. `element.click()` almost never works and `casper.click(sel)` almost always works, but there are times where it doesn't work. There is a reason why there are multiple ways to do the *seemingly* same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is more general than specific, I will try to answer in the same vein.

fill and fillSelectors are there to quickly fill simple forms.

If you have javascript heavy websites, with events being triggered on actions, then you have SendKeys, which will try to trigger those events as they go.

Finally, if SendKeys does not do the job, you can always go with evaluate and trigger those events manually. If you open your browser console and inspect elements you want to make action on, you will see the events attached to them. From there, you can see if they are DOM events or JQuery events, so you can use document.querySelector or $ accordingly. Before coding anything, know that if you jump to your browser javascript console, any code that you execute there will be what you will end up having in your evaluate scope ; You can quickly test your code in your browser before applying it to your script.

I did not go in details, I just went through the surface of "fill() vs evaluate() vs sendKeys()" with my personal experience but to answer your question specifically, we do not have the page HTML so it is hard to tell. There would be many reasons why SendKeys would not work but not evaluate. In your evaluate scope, the selectors might be wrong or an event is missing.

Finally, as Artjom mentioned, for clicking it's always best to go with casper.click(selector)